# How to extend laravel Illuminate\Translation\Translator class

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance

I want to extend this class `Illuminate\Translation\Translator` which extends `\Illuminate\Support\NamespacedItemResolver`

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Translation;

use Countable;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;
use Illuminate\Support\NamespacedItemResolver;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Translator as TranslatorContract;

class Translator extends NamespacedItemResolver implements TranslatorContract
{
    use Macroable;
}
```

I extended `\Illuminate\Support\NamespacedItemResolver` into my own class

but when I call `Translator` its still taking the base class's functions.
which is `\Illuminate\Support\NamespacedItemResolver`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

class NamespaceParser extends \Illuminate\Support\NamespacedItemResolver
{
}
```

**UPDATE**

created a new Translator class and tried to extend it in the `AppServiceProvider`
and the below **WORKED**

```
public function register()
   {
         $loader = $this->app['translation.loader'];

        // When registering the translator component, we'll need to set the default
        // locale as well as the fallback locale. So, we'll grab the application
        // configuration so we can easily get both of these values from there.
        $locale = $this->app['config']['app.locale'];

       $this->app->extend('translator', function () {
             new \App\Repositories\Translator($loader, $locale);
       });
   }
```

Comment: can you share whole code so i can help you to resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to achieve is kind of advanced and is described here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#extending-bindings

An example of a package that does this very thing can be found here:

https://github.com/onlinepets/laravel-conditional-migrations/blob/master/src/ServiceProvider.php

You have to tell Laravel to use your custom class from now on, instead of the default one.

**Summary**

You have to tell the Laravel Service Container to use another class than normal. You do this by calling `$this->app->extend` in the register function of a Service Provider.

Comment: hey I tried to extend it.. but it has 2 passed arguments in the construct.. how can I extend?

getting this error

Comment: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Repositories\Translator::__construct() must be an instance of App\Repositories\LoaderInterface, instance of Illuminate\Translation\Translator given, called in /home/garine/Documents/toters-api/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php on line 48
`

Comment: Does it change if you do not type `new Translator` but `app('Translator')` for resolving an instance? This is because it uses dependency injection that way

Comment: `Target [Illuminate\Translation\LoaderInterface] is not instantiable while building [\App\Repositories\Translator].` @ThomasMoors

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @ThomasMoors

Comment: @Garine If this anwer helped you, you might want to upvote it and / or accept it. That way I get some points and other people can see it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me in Laravel 6:

```php
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->extend(\Illuminate\Translation\Translator::class, function ($translator) {
            return new \App\Translation\Translator($translator->getLoader(), $translator->getLocale());
        });
    }
```

Should be added to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`